# Selenium firefox opens 2 firefox (With CDI)

Tags: firefox, selenium, cdi

I'm using selenium with CDI to create it, every time i use it, selenium opens 2 firefox and just use one, leaving the other one open.

I'm creating the FirefoxDriver with CDI so i can inject and use it on various places.
They way i'm creating:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class FirefoxDriverProducer {

    @RequestScoped
    @Produces 
    public FirefoxDriver getDriver() {
        String caminhoFirefox = "/usr/bin/firefox";
        String profileFirefox = "selenium";

        File pathToBinary = new File(caminhoFirefox);
        FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);

        ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile(profileFirefox);

        return new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary, myprofile);
    }

    public void close(@Disposes FirefoxDriver driver) {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

To use it, i'm just doing like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Crawler {

    @Inject
    private FirefoxDriver driver;

    public void Crawl(){
        driver.get("http://siteimcrawling.com");
    }
}
```

Why is it opening 2 Firefox instead of one?